# Scrapy + heroku: no module named 'twisted mail'

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy, twisted

I'm trying to run a `Scrapy` spider on `heroku`. Here is my `requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==0.10.1
gunicorn==0.17.2
requests==2.4.3
python-dateutil==2.2
cffi==1.5.0
Scrapy==1.0.5
Twisted==15.5.0
```

And when I pushed the app to `heroku`, the logs said that `Twisted` was installed successfully. Some where in code I have:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

def crawl():
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

    process.crawl(WallpaperSpider)
    process.start()
    return wallpaper_url
```

But I get the following error, when I try to run that code on `heroku`:

> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py",
>   line 46, in **init**
>
> File "/app/netimen.py", line 141, in wallpaper
>
> ImportError: No module named 'twisted.mail'

What am I doing wrong here? I never import `twisted.mail` directly. It seems, it's imported by `scrapy`

Comment: You're using Python 3.4 and twisted mail is not available in Python 3.. What version of Scrapy are you using? Scrapy on Python3 does not support sending email (may never do). Scrapy 1.1rc1 imports `twisted.mail` [in `scrapy.mail.MailSender::_sendmail`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.1.0rc1/scrapy/mail.py#L105). It should only happen when actually sending mail. A couple of extensions can send mail: `scrapy.extensions.statsmailer.StatsMailer` and `scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage`. Are  you using any of those?

Comment: I'm using scrapy `1.0.5` and don't want to send any emails. All these imports happen somewehe inside srapy

Comment: Saw your answer. Indeed, scrapy 1.0.5 is not supported on Python 3. Scrapy 1.1 is the first release supporting Python 3 (only 1.1rc1 available as I write this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed when I just upgraded `scrapy` to version `1.1rc1`.